# document.querySelector returns null, but element exists

Tags: javascript, error-handling

At the moment, I'm trying to set up an automatic change in the height of the center element (class='main') depending on the height of the header and footer using javascript. The script is like this:

```
const headerHeight = document.querySelector('header').clientHeight;
const footerHeight = document.querySelector('footer').clientHeight;
const mainElement = document.querySelector('main');

changeMainBlockHeight();

function changeMainBlockHeight() {
    const resultMainHeight = pageHeight - headerHeight - footerHeight;
    mainElement.setAttribute('style', `height: ${resultMainHeight}px`);
}
```

If i choose in querySelector main element, you can see that everything is normal, no errors, and the summ height of the elements is really 100vh: [no error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iaj61.png).
But if I choose container instead of the main element (this is the first child element of the main element) in the 3rd code line `const mainElement = document.querySelector('main')`, and line becomes `const mainElement = document.querySelector('container')` i get this error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5Qxh.png)
This also happens with some other elements other than the container, but I think this is enough for an example.
Also, this warning often appears :"Layout was forced before the page was fully loaded. If stylesheets are not yet loaded this may cause a flash of unstyled content.". This may have something to do with the error that occurs, but I couldn't find a cause and solution.
I will be grateful for any help! :)

List item

Comment: Kindly share the corresponding HTML you are trying to query as well. Most probably, you are using a div with class container which has to be queried using `document.querySelector('.container')`. It can be only confirmed from your HTML.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70218523/why-is-my-document-queryselector-returning-null

Answer (score 0):

Your container is a div with class container so you should query “.container” (with dot) not just “container”

Comment: thanks for the answer! I thought that I was accessing the main, footer, and header elements using the same classes that I named them, and I didn't understand why querySelector doesn't see other elements.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the query selector, you have to be precise for it to understand.

If you want to call an HTML tag like `body`, `div` or `p` you don't need to put anything else in your string for queryselector.

But here, since you want to call a class, you have to use the notation "." before your class name to specify to the query selector that you are looking for a class.

```
const mainElement = document.querySelector('.main');
```

The same applies for ids and the #.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I thought that I was accessing the main, footer, and header elements using the same classes that I named them, and I didn't understand why querySelector doesn't see other elements.

Answer (score 0):

My challenge (putting this here in the hopes somebody can benefit from it) was a race condition - I needed to wait for the page to finish loading before javascript could find the elements.  Might not be obvious to folks that don't do much javascript.

```
window.onload = function(){ /* your code goes here */ }
```